# Configurable Product created with existing SKUs won't let users add to cart?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, search, advanced-pricing

For background, I had 16 existing SKUs that were essentially the same product but in different sizes (Industrial burs, with different sized heads). They all have their own individual product pages, and it was a really cluttered, overwhelming customer experience.

To remedy, I went to Products> Catalog> Add Configurable Product and created a new product with same naming convention as the 16 existing SKUs, just leaving out the size descriptions from the title. I then went into each of the 16 SKUs and added a size attribute to them. I went back to the New Configurable Product, added a dummy SKU to get the "Enter Products Manually" option to appear, then went in and added all 16 existing SKUs to the configuration and removed the dummy SKU.

The issue I'm having is that when I'm on the configurable product page, I have the option to select any of my sizes as was my goal, BUT I can't add anything to my cart. I'm met with a "Request Pricing" Button instead (which we use intentionally for other products on the site, but not for any of the 16 SKUs that were variated). I should also mention that we have advanced pricing set up for these 16 SKUs where the price would decrease as a higher quantity was ordered- this option is not showing up either in the configurable page. I am unsure if that is what's causing the Request pricing issue or not, but it's also another issue we need help with as those price breaks are important to keep.

I also noticed that now when I search the products, all 16 SKUs do still pop up individually with their own product pages plus the new configuarble product, so there's a total of 17 options instead of the desired 1, defeating the purpose of cleaning up the overwhelming search results.

I am hoping somebody can tell me how to fix these issues!
We are using Magento version 2.1.7

Comment: to stop the child products of the configurable product from appearing in search or the catalog set their visibility to “not visible individually”. Does your advanced pricing code support configurable products? Do you have any other configurable products where it works?

Comment: The “not visible individually” works for that issue, thank you.

This is our first attempt at creating configurable products, so we have no history of it working with or without the advanced pricing mechanism.